# HTML CSS ul li auto width

Tags: html, css

I have looked around for an answer to this question, but with no luck!

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

What I want is for the tabs `ul li` to auto-width depending on the amount of tabs that there are on the certain page. The number of tabs on each page will change, but I can not find a way to make the tabs auto-width.

The code:

```css
#tabs {
  height: 30px;
}

#tabs>ul {
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#tabs>ul>li {
  margin: 0 0px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: #C9C9C9;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li id="tabHeader_1">Page 1</li>
    <li id="tabHeader_2">Page 2</li>
    <li id="tabHeader_3">Page 3</li>
    <li id="tabHeader_4">Page 4</li>
    <li id="tabHeader_5">Page 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab_1">
  <h2>Page 1</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
</div>
<div class="tabpage" id="tab_2">
  <h2>Page 2</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
</div>
<div class="tabpage" id="tab_3">
  <h2>Page 3</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
</div>
<div class="tabpage" id="tab_4">
  <h2>Page 3</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
</div>
<div class="tabpage" id="tab_5">
  <h2>Page 3</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus...</p>
</div>
```

All the attempts have failed to make the `<li>`'s auto-width. All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: remove `float: left;` from `#tabs > ul > li` css rule.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make couple of changes.

- Remove `float: left` from `#tabs>ul>li`
- Remove side padding from `#tabs>ul` so ul can take full width.

After updating your css should look like this.

```
#tabs {
  height: 30px;
}

#tabs>ul {
  font-size: 1em;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding: 0;
}

#tabs>ul>li {
  margin: 0 0px 0 0;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  display: block;
  display: table-cell;
  width: auto;
  background: #C9C9C9;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
body{
      background:#ededed;
      margin:0 auto;
  }
  .container{
      width:720px;
      border:1px solid red;
      padding:5px;
  }
ul{
    list-style:none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ul > li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
           <div class="container">
              <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```